# Using Default and Custom MKPointAnnotation on the same map in iOS

Tags: ios

I have a map on which I want to display both custom annotations with images and one default looking annotation with a red pin.

I've made my view into a map delegate in order to load the custom images, but what happens is that the default looking pin I want is not showing (since I don't load an image for it).

I'm adding a shortened version of my code below (with remarks).

How can I load an image for this pin? Is there a standard way to access the pin UIImage, or should I make the annotation somehow?

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *SFAnnotationIdentifier = @"SFAnnotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView =
    (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:SFAnnotationIdentifier];

    MKPointAnnotation* pointAnnotation = (MKPointAnnotation*)annotation;

    if (!pinView)
    {
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                     reuseIdentifier:SFAnnotationIdentifier];

        for (id location in self.locations) {
            // if this is a "special" point loaded 
            if () {
                UIImage *image = ; // get custom image from somewhere 

                annotationView.image = image;
                return annotationView;
            }
        }

        // if the code made here, I want the pin to be regular 

        return annotationView;
    }
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return pinView;
}
```

Comment: Don't loop through locations in the delegate method.  Use some property of the `annotation` parameter to determine whether it is a "special" point and _then_ dequeue/create either an MKPinAnnotationView or MKAnnotationView.

Answer (score 2):

OK, solved it.

```
return nil;
```

does the trick and gives the default view.

Comment: Where did you add it?

Comment: // if the code made here, I want the pin to be regular

Comment: Putting that code there means that after the user pans or zooms the map, it's possible for the "special" annotation to get a dequeued "regular" view instead (because you're using the same re-use id for both types of annotations).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
UIImage *image = ; // get custom image from somewhere
```

to

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourPin.png"]; // get custom image from somewhere
```

And maybe you need to change the offset of annotationView

```
annotationView.centerOffset = CGPointMake( 0, annotationView.centerOffset.y - annotationView.image.size.height/2 );
```